# Implicit expansion with dependant types

Tags: scala, types, implicit-conversion

I wonder why the following case doesn't work. Let's say i have two types:

```
trait Def[T]
trait Ref[T]
case class Module()
```

And i want to convert a `Def` to `Ref`, so i'm declaring the following method:

```
object Ref {
  implicit def fromDef[A](defin: Def[A])(implicit rc: RefConverter[A]): Ref[rc.ResType] = new Ref[rc.ResType] {}
}
```

But in case:

```
val moduleDef: Def[Module] = ???
val moduleRef: Ref[Module] = moduleDef
```

Scala compiler can't find the right way to convert it (i.e `fromDef` function), but if we explicitly tell it to use this convertion, i.e `Ref.fromDef(moduleDef)`, scalac would find the right `RefConverter` instance. Another important thing to consider is that if i change the result type to `Ref[A]` it would also resolve the convertion chain. So the compiler can't resolve the chain with dependant result type?

Comment: What is the difference between #ResType and #RefType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tie the type param and the type member together.

You can provide an alias as in the other answer; note it doesn't work with a type bound in the trait, see the code comment.

But you can provide another type param that is bounded:

```
trait Ref[T]
trait Def[T]
case class Module()

object Ref {
  //implicit def fromDef[A](defin: Def[A])(implicit rr: RefResolver[A]): Ref[rr.RefType] = new Ref[rr.RefType] {}
  //implicit def fromDef[A](defin: Def[A])(implicit rr: RefResolver[A]): Ref[A] = new Ref[A] {}  // OP notes that this works
  implicit def fromDef[A, B <: A](defin: Def[A])(implicit rr: RefResolver[B]): Ref[B] = new Ref[B] {}
  // or
  implicit def fromDef[A](defin: Def[A])(implicit rr: RefResolver[A]): Ref[A] { type RefType <: A } = new Ref[A] { type RefType = A }
}

trait RefResolver[A] {
  type RefType
  //type RefType <: A    // not good enough
}

object RefResolver {
  implicit val moduleRes: RefResolver[Module] { type RefType = Module } =
    new RefResolver[Module] {
      type RefType = Module
    }
}

object Test extends App {
  val moduleDef: Def[Module] = new Def[Module] {}
  val moduleRef: Ref[Module] = moduleDef
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution and answers the question, but really not very practical cause it constraints the dependant type to `A`, so if i have an independant type `ModuleId` and want to write `val moduleRef: Ref[ModuleId] = moduleDef` this won't work

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles:

```
trait Def[T]
trait Ref[T]
case class Module()

trait RefConverter[T]{
  type ResType = T
  type RefType = T
}
object Ref {
  implicit def fromDef[A](defin: Def[A])(implicit rc: RefConverter[A]): Ref[rc.ResType] = new Ref[rc.RefType] {}
}
implicit val rc = new RefConverter[Module]{}
val d = new Def[Module]{}
val r = d:Ref[Module]
```

Comment: Arseniy, i'm very sorry, but this was just a typo, there's only a `ResType`

Answer (score 0):

This compiles and prints types:

```
object Test extends App {

  implicit val rc = new RefConverter[Module] {}

  object Ref {
    implicit def fromDef[A](defin: Def[A])(implicit rc: RefConverter[A]): Ref[rc.ResType] = new Ref[rc.ResType] {}
  }

  val moduleDef: Def[Module] = new Def[Module]() {}
  val moduleRef: Ref[Module] = moduleDef

  println(moduleDef.getClass.getName)
  println(moduleRef.getClass.getName)

  trait RefConverter[T] {
    type ResType = T
  }

  trait Def[T]

  trait Ref[T]

  case class Module()
}
```

I assume your Refconverter is either not in scope, or you have been mislead by our IDE underlining this as an error.